# Form checkbox input array gets flooded with textarea input

Tags: laravel, forms, checkbox

)

I have been struggling with a form for my Laravel App....
I have 3 fields which are checkboxes and therefore is getting POSTed as arrays and then I have a textarea field and somehow SOMETIMES one of the 3 checkbox inputs get flooded with data from the textarea input field... It is very weird and only happens sometime and therefore I get a data to long truncated error in the database...

But I DD the input at the $request level and can see already there the array from the checkbox is flooded with the data from the textarea field... I can not wrap my head around why this is, as it's only sometimes...
And I can even get the error and go back a page in the browser and submit again with all the same data and then it can be working.. WHAT can cause this weird behavioer

This is my Laravel blade where the form is

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('head')
@endsection

@section('content')
@php 
// dd($errors);
@endphp
<h2 class="page-title">Opret Artist Side</h2>
<div class="artist-box"> 
    <form class="formgrid" method="POST" action="{{ route('artist.store') }}">
        @csrf
        <div class="formleft">
            <label for="artist_name" class="label">Artist navn</label>
            <input type="text" id="artist_name" name="artist_name" class="formitem @error('artist_name') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('artist_name', $post->artist_name ?? null) }}" />
            
            @error('artist_name')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @foreach($errors->get('artist_name') as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @else 
                <small class="text-muted form-text" id="artist_name_help">Jeres band/artist navn. <span class="text-danger">OBS! Kan IKKE ændres</span></small>
            @enderror    
        </div>

        
        <div class="formright">
            <label for="contact_person" class="label">Kontakt person</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_person" id="contact_person" class="formitem @error('contact_person') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('contact_person', $post->content ?? null) }}" />
            
            @error('contact_person')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @foreach($errors->get('contact_person') as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @else 
                <small class="text-muted form-text" id="contact_person_help">Kontakt persons navn</small>
            @enderror    
        </div>
            

        <div class="formleft">
            <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="formitem @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('email', $post->email ?? null) }}" />
            
            @error('email')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @foreach($errors->get('email') as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @else 
                <small class="text-muted form-text" id="email_help">Kontakt email</small>
            @enderror
        </div>


        <div class="formright">
            <label for="phone" class="label">Tlf nummer</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="formitem @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('phone', $post->phone ?? null) }}" />
            
            @error('phone')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @foreach($errors->get('phone') as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @else 
                <small class="text-muted form-text" id="phone_help">Kontakt tlf nummer</small>
            @enderror
        </div>

        
        <div class="formleft">
            <label for="hometown" class="label">Hjemby</label>
            <input type="text" name="hometown" id="hometown" class="formitem @error('hometown') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('hometown', $post->hometown ?? null) }}" />
            
            @error('hometown')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @foreach($errors->get('hometown') as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @else 
                <small class="text-muted form-text" id="hometown_help">Jeres Hjemby</small>
            @enderror
        </div>


        <div class="formright">
            <label for="category" class="label">Kategori</label>
            <select name="category" id="category" class="formitem @error('category') is-invalid @enderror">
                {{-- Show a non selectable if with info of none selected --}}
                @if(old('category') === null)
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected value="null">Vælg en kategori</option>
                @endif
                
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <option @if(old('category') !== null && old('category') == $category->id) selected @endif value="{{ $category->id }}"
                        >{{ $category->artist_category }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            
            @error('category')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @foreach($errors->get('category') as $error)
                        {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @else 
                <small class="text-muted form-text" id="">Hvilken kategori hører i under</small>
            @enderror
        </div>

        
        <div class="formfull">
            <label for="budget" class="label">Budget i spiller for</label>
            <ul class="ks-cboxtags">
            @foreach($budgets as $budget)
                {{-- <div class="form-check form-check-inline"> --}}
                <li><input @if(old('budget') !== null && in_array($budget->id,old('budget'))) checked @endif
                type="checkbox" name="budget[]" id="budget{{ $budget->id }}" class="form-check-input @error('budget') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ $budget->id }}" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="budget{{ $budget->id }}">{{ $budget->artist_budget }}</label></li>
                {{-- </div> --}}
            @endforeach
            </ul>
            
            @error('budget')
                <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
                    @foreach($errors->get('budget') as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @else 
                <small class="text-muted form-text" id="budget_help">Vælg hvilket budget i optræder for, gerne flere</small>
            @enderror           
        </div>
        
        {{--  --}}
        <div class="formfull">
            <label for="genres" class="label">Genre</label>
            <ul class="ks-cboxtags">
            @foreach($genres as $genre)
                {{-- <div class="form-check form-check-inline"> --}}
                <li><input @if(old('genres') !== null && in_array($genre->id,old('genres'))) checked @endif
                type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres{{ $genre->id }}" value="{{ $genre->id }}" class="form-check-input @error('genres') is-invalid @enderror" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="genres{{ $genre->id }}">{{ $genre->genre }}</label></li>
                {{-- </div> --}}
            @endforeach
            </ul>
            
            @error('genres')
                <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
                    @foreach($errors->get('genres') as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @else 
                <small class="text-muted form-text" id="">Hvike genrer hører i under</small>
            @enderror           
        </div>
        {{--  --}}

        <div class="formfull">
            <label for="area" class="label">Områder hvor i optræder</label>
            <ul class="ks-cboxtags">
            @foreach($areas as $area)
                {{-- <div class="form-check form-check-inline"> --}}
                <li><input @if(old('area') !== null && in_array($area->id,old('area'))) checked @endif
                type="checkbox" name="area[]" id="area{{ $area->id }}" value="{{ $area->id }}" class="form-check-input @error('area') is-invalid @enderror" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="area{{ $area->id }}">{{ $area->artist_area }}</label></li>
                {{-- </div> --}}
            @endforeach
            </ul>
            
            @error('area')
                <div class="invalid-feedback d-block">
                    @foreach($errors->get('area') as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @else 
                <small class="text-muted form-text" id="">Vælg hvilke områder i optræder i</small>
            @enderror           
        </div>

     
        <div class="formleft">
            <label for="desc" class="label">Beskriv jer selv</label>
            <textarea name="description" id="description" class="formitem @error('description') is-invalid @enderror">{{ old('description', $post->description ?? null) }}</textarea>
            
            {{-- <input id="description" value="{{ old('description', $post->description ?? null) }}" class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror" name="description" type="hidden">
            @trix(\App\ArtistPage::class, 'trixinput',
            [
            'id' => 'description',
            // 'class' => 'form-control',
            'hideTools' => ['file-tools'],
            'hideButtonIcons' => ['attach', 'link', 'code', 'strike', 'heading-1']
            ]) --}}
            
            {{-- <input id="desc" value="{{ old('description', $post->description ?? null) }}" type="hidden" name="description">
            <trix-editor input="desc" class="@error('description') is-invalid @enderror"></trix-editor> --}}
            @error('description')
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    @foreach($errors->get('description') as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @else 
            <small class="text-muted form-text" id="description_help">Giv en god beskrivelse af jer selv og hvad i tilbyder<br>
                Tilladte tags er <strong>{{ '<br><b><i><li><ul><ol><hr><strong><p>' }}</strong>
            </small>
            @enderror           
        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Opret</button>
    </form>
</div>

    @endsection
```

See also this image of the DD dump on the $request

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm Think I figured it out :-)
But it has been such a sporadic bug so I'm not sure yet... But seems like it has gone away :-)

Seems like it was this value line on each field I have gotten messed up

The value line structure on the input fields I had was

```
value="{{ old('artist_name', $post->artist_name ?? null) }}"
```

And it should be

```
value="{{ old('artist_name') ?? $post->artist_name ?? null }}"
```

Dont know why I ended up with such an obscure Value part on every input field :-)
But sometimes the eyes just gets blind on code :-)